# Python: Replace function to edit files

Tags: python, file, replace

I have a `results.txt` file which looks like this:

```
[["12 - 22 - 30 - 31 - 34 - 39 - 36"],
["13 - 21 - 28 - 37 - 39 - 45 - 6"],
["2 - 22 - 32 - 33 - 37 - 45 - 11"],
["3 - 5 - 11 - 16 - 41 - 48 - 32"],
["2 - 3 - 14 - 29 - 35 - 42 12"],
["14 - 30 - 31 - 36 - 44 - 47 26"]]
```

I want to replace the " - " in the results.txt file with '","' so it looks for like a python list.

I try to used the code below, but the output looks exactly like the results.txt

```
output = open("results2.txt", 'w')
f = open("results.txt", 'r')
read = f.readlines()

for i in read:
    i.replace(" - ",'","')
    output.write(i)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for i in read:
    # the string.replace() function don't do the change at place
    # it's return a new string with the new changes.
    a = i.replace(" - ",",")  
    output.write(a)
```

Answer (score 5):

String methods return a new string. Write that out instead.

```
output.write(i.replace(" - ",","))
```

Answer (score 4):

`i.replace(" - ",'","')` doesn't change `i` (remember strings are immutable) so you should use

```
i = i.replace(" - ",'","')
```

If the file isn't very big ( I am guessing - since you are reading it all into memory at once with `readlines()` anyway), you can just do the whole file at once

```
output = open("results2.txt", 'w')
f = open("results.txt", 'r')
output.write(f.read().replace(" - ".'","'))
f.close()
output.close()
```